# Quartz.NET from config.xml in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net

Can someone advise on what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to setup quartz so that on startup it will read an xml config file. Inside the file there is a job that activates my `HelloEmail_Job.cs` class (it is created correctly, extending `IJob` with the logic in the execute method). The xml also has a cron trigger for the job that will fire every minute (purely for testing).

But everything starts up without an error, but the job never fires. I am sure I am configuring wrong.

I have a singleton that handles the generation of my scheduler, the scheduler starts on startup of my app (in the `global.asax` file)

```
    NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
    properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteServer";

    ////// set thread pool info
    properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";

    properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
    properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";

    properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Data Source=CRAIG-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCWdb;User ID=sa;Password=mastercrud;";
    properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";

    // job initialization plugin handles our xml reading, without it defaults are used
    properties["quartz.plugin.xml.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz";
    properties["quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames"] = "~/quartz_jobs.xml";

    ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    _sched = sf.GetScheduler();
```

My `quartz_jobs.xml` file looks like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        version="2.0">

          <processing-directives>
            <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
          </processing-directives>

          <schedule>        
                <job> 
                  <job-detail> 
                    <name>MyJob</name> 
                    <group>MyJobs</group> 
                    <description>sends out a test email</description>
                      <job-type>HelloEmail_Job</job-type>
                      <volatile>false</volatile> 
                    <durable>true</durable> 
                    <recover>false</recover> 
                    <job-data-map> 
                      <entry> 
                        <key>Body</key> 
                        <value>Hello From your website!!!!!!!!</value> 
                      </entry> 
                    </job-data-map> 
                  </job-detail> 
                  <trigger> 
                    <cron> 
                      <name>MyJobTrigger</name> 
                      <group>MyJobs</group> 
                      <description>A description</description> 
                      <job-name>MyJob</job-name> 
                      <job-group>MyJobs</job-group> 
                      <cron-expression>0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression> 
                    </cron> 
                  </trigger> 
                </job>
            </schedule>

        </job-scheduling-data>
```

I know that the scheduler is running correctly for *ad hoc* jobs with a simple trigger because when my app creates them and schedules them dynamically it works perfectly. But I want the logic made repeatable (through a cron), and configurable through a xml.

My gut feeling is that the JOB_TYPE value is wrong.

Comment: note: this is a WEB SITE, and my HelloEmail_Job.cs file lives in APP_CODE\scheduler\jobs. if this helps at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your job type needs to be specified as

```
<job-type>Fully.Qualified.Type.Name, AssemblyNameWithoutTheDllExtension</job-type>
```

Comment: Thanks. question about this tho. mine is an asp.net website. my class lives in the app_code folder. i havent compiled my website into a dll. how do i determine the fully qualified name? Thanks!

Comment: var name=yourVariable.GetType().Name gets you the name, .Namespace gives you the namespace and .Assembly gives you the assembly name. I don't know if you will be able to load if from app code because I am assuming the assembly name will change each time it's compiled.

Comment: thanks. your tip showed me what was wrong. my app_code folder was getting funny names because it gets dynamically compiled. if i precompile my app, it is sorted. so all a do is <job-type>HelloJob,APP_CODE</job-type> thanks for the help