# asp.net website fully qualified path and assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net

A requirement for a 3rd party config is that i supply it with:
1. Fully.Qualified.Type.Name,
2. AssemblyNameWithoutTheDllExtension
of a specific class

now this should be easy, but I am not sure how to solve this.
I have an asp.net website (web forms)
All my classes live in a sub folder inside my APP_CODE folder
my classes are just plain cs files, not dlls
Everything is in the global namespace

(note, 3rd party is Quartz.net see previous thread
([My previous Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296383/quartz-net-from-config-xml-in-asp-net))

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question was answered in my [Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325022/351383) thread. but to keep it generic for future googelers:

note - answer came from [jvilalta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167388/jvilalta)

> var name=yourVariable.GetType().Name gets you the name, .Namespace
>   gives you the namespace and .Assembly gives you the assembly name. I
>   don't know if you will be able to load if from app code because I am
>   assuming the assembly name will change each time it's compiled

So you would need to pre-build your web site to generate the app_code.dll in the bin folder
then you can easily go

```
<job-type>Fully.Qualified.Type.Name, AssemblyNameWithoutTheDllExtension</job-type>
```

or in my case

```
<job-type>HelloJob, App_Code</job-type>
```