# Quartz .NET job-type configuration issues

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I've been dumbfounded by what I suspect is an oversight on my part in the setting up of a Quartz .NET configuration file.  I've searched the forum for similar posts, with this post '[quartz.net from config xml in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296383/quartz-net-from-config-xml-in-asp-net)' being the most relevant, but unfortunately it has not helped.  I'd appreciate any help or advice people can think of.

I am attempting to load a configuration file to schedule some jobs using Quartz version 1.  My app.config file defines the the Quartz configuration:

```
<quartz>
        <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="QuartzScheduler" />
        <!-- Configure Thread Pool -->
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
        <!-- Configure Job Store -->
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
        <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.JobInitializationPlugin, Quartz" />
        <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="~/configuration/quartz_jobs.config" />
        <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.scanInterval" value="10" />
    </quartz>
```

Then my quartz_jobs.config file defines the jobs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quartz xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                version="1.0"
                overwrite-existing-jobs="true">

    <job>
        <job-detail>
            <name>jobName1</name>
            <group>jobGroup1</group>
            <description>jobDesciption1</description>
            <job-type>FundDataImportScheduler.Jobs.FsdImportJob, FundDataImportScheduler</job-type>
            <volatile>false</volatile>
            <durable>true</durable>
            <recover>false</recover>
        </job-detail>

        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>cronName1</name>
                <group>cronGroup1</group>
                <description>CronTriggerDescription</description>
                <job-name>jobName1</job-name>
                <job-group>jobGroup1</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 0/1 * * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </job>
</quartz>
```

Please note the  node in the quartz_jobs.config file.  I am trying to load the class that implements IJob:

```
public class FsdImportJob : IJob
{
   public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("FsdImportJob triggered");
   }
}
```

The issue I am having is, when the  node equals "FundDataImportScheduler.Jobs.FsdImportJob, FundDataImportScheduler", the job is not loaded.  If I test using a value of "Quartz.Job.NativeJob, Quartz" in the  node, a job is loaded (not the one I want though).

FundDataImportScheduler.Jobs.FsdImportJob is the exact namespace of the class FsdImportJob, and FundDataImportScheduler is the dll it is compiled into.

For completeness, the code I am using to build the Quartz SchedulerFactory and load the configuration is:

```
ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
scheduler.Start();
```

I would appreciate any pointers as to where I am going wrong.

Many thanks,

Chima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now I feel a bit silly - the problem was because I initially had the FsdImportJob class in console app. Quartz was expecting a FundDataImportScheduler.dll, but of course there was only a FundDataImportScheduler.exe.

Once I moved the FsdImportJob out into a class library, Quartz was able to load the .dll the library compiled, and thus load the FsdImportJob class.

Many thanks,

Chima

Comment: Seems like a sensible assumption!